# Can you activate an activated ability more than once per turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am using the card [Blood Bairn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blood%20Bairn), which has the following activated ability:

> Sacrifice another creature: Blood Bairn gets +2/+2 until end of turn.

I use my Blood Bairn in conjunction with [Festering Newt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Festering%20Newt)s, which allow me to give a target creature -1/-1 when it dies. The sacrifice allows it to die and lets me hurt a creature. If I have, say, 2 Festering Newts on the field, can I activate Blood Bairn's ability with both Festering Newts, allowing me to not only give -1/-1 to 2 target creatures but also giving Blood Bairn +4/+4?

Comment: +1 for phrasing the title in a nice, general way instead of just asking for a specific ability on a specific card!

Comment: Two notes: 1) Abilities with {T} in their cost are no exception. You can use them more than once per turn if you can pay the cost. This would require you having some means of untapping the permanent since you can't tap something already tapped. 2) For any given Planeswalker, only one of its loyalty abilities can be used per turn, and only once.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes, there is no restriction in the rules that prevents a player from paying the costs of an activated ability twice, to get the effect twice.**

An [Activated Ability](http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Activated_ability) is the only ability that can be activated. You may activate it whenever, and as many times as you like, as long as you have priority by paying the **cost**.

> 602.1. Activated abilities have a cost and an effect. They are written as "[Cost]: [Effect.] [Activation instructions (if any).]"
>
> 602.1a The activation cost is everything before the colon (:). An ability's activation cost must be paid by the player who is activating it.

Unless the ability itself restricts its usage.

> 602.5b If an activated ability has a restriction on its use (for example, "Activate this ability only once each turn"), the restriction continues to apply to that object even if its controller changes.

Comment: Excellent--That just adds to my strategy more. Thanks! :)